# Propel auto generated classes

Tags: propel

I have given a project that is written in **codeIgnotor** and **Propel 1.6** as ORM. The only ORM I have used is Eloquent so its really confusing for me to see all these classes in Propel.

When I run propel bat file with defined schema I get three classes e.g

For user I get

```
1 - User.php       extends    BaseUser
2 - UserPeer.php   extends    BaseUserPeer
3 - UserQuery.php  extends    BaseUserQuery
```

According to propel documentation Peer Class is for backward compatibility what does that mean.

And also If some one could please explain what type of fuctions one would define inside each class.

Also there is **om** folder in auto generated build. Is it a good idea to add your method inside these classes.

Any help would be realllly appreciated. If someone could use **User** example to explain.

Answer (score 2):

1. Here's a very good Propel article for that: [Propel By Example](http://propelorm.org/blog/2010/02/16/propel-query-by-example.html)
2. User.php represents a row in the `User` table, and your query/update logic in UserQuery.php
3. The **om** folder contains class definitions from which your "User" is extended, so don't touch the folder, it gets overwritten everytime you build your model

**Examples for #2 above**:

Scenario #1: When a User is updated, set `TimeUpdated` column to the unix current time.

Scenario #2: You want be able to get a Users Full Name

Implementation:

```
<?php
class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function preUpdate(PropelPDO $oConn=null)
    {
        $this->setTimeUpdated(time());
    return true;
    }// Will be executed everytime you call '->save()' on an existing row

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getFirstName() . ' ' . $this->getLastName();
    }
...
```

Usage for scenario #2:

```
$User = UserQuery::create()->findPk(1);
echo 'FirstName: ' . $User->getName();
```

Scenario #3: You want to add a filter for Male teen users
Implementation:

```
<?php
class UserQuery extends BaseUserQuery
{
    public function MaleTeen()
    {
        return $this
            ->filterByGender('M')
            ->filterByAge([
                'min' => 13,
                'max' => 19
            ]);
    }
...
```

Usage: `$Teens = UserQuery::create()->MaleTeen()->find(); // Did someone say D.R.Y?`

I hope it helps.